# Build a table layout from JSON data (code improvement)

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object like below and I am converting the JSON to HTML with below wrapper function

Portion retrieved from JSON:

```
var data = { "Column Headers" : [ // Hierarchy is not limited to two levels, it is n level
    [  "Column1" , ["Column1's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2"] ], 
    [  "Column2" , ["Column2's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2"] ],
    [  "Column3" , ["Column3's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2"] ]  
],
"Columns under subColumns" : ["I am column 1", "I am column 2"],
"Data for Table" :[
    { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group 1"], "data" : [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]]},
    { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group 2"], "data" : [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]]},
    { "name": ["Group 2","Sub Group 1"], "data" : [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]]},
    { "name": ["Group 2","Sub Group 2"], "data" : [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]]}
], // here the hierarchy is not limited to two sub groups.. it could be any number..
"row group headers" : ["Group 1 Header", "Sub group Header"]
}
```

It should be compiled to HTML like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RwdWq/

And here is the code that I have written

```
 var render = function(data){
    var formattedData = {};
    function returnRowsData( obj ) {
      return obj["Data for Table"];
    }
    function returnColsData(obj) {
      return obj["Column Headers"];
    }
    function rowLabels(obj) {
      return obj["row group headers"];
    }
    function bottomColLabels(obj) {
      return obj["Columns under subColumns"];
    }
    function simplifyCols(obj) {
      var reform = {
        table : {}
      }, bottomLabs = bottomColLabels(data);
      var y = 0;
      for(var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++){
        var key = obj[i];
        key.push(bottomLabs);
        for (var j = 0, m = key.length; j < m; j++) {
           var colspan = 1;
           for (var k = j + 1; k < m; k++) {
              colspan *= key[k].length; 
           }
           reform.table[j] = reform.table[j] || [];
           if (j == 0) {
            y += colspan;
           }
           reform.table[j].push({
             span : colspan,
             data : key[j]
           });
          }
        }
        reform.count = y;
        return reform;
     }
     var formatted = simplifyCols( returnColsData( data[0]) ) || {};
     var cols = formatted.table;
     //console.log(cols);
     formattedData.cols = cols;
     var keys = Object.keys(cols).sort(function(a, b){
         return a - b;
     });
     var table = document.createElement('table');
     for (var i = 0, l = keys.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
        var keyData = cols[keys[i]], tr = document.createElement('tr');
        if (i == 0) {
            var rLs = rowLabels(data[0]);
            for (var rL = 0; rL < rLs.length; rL++) {
              var td = document.createElement('th');
              td.innerHTML = rLs[rL];
                td.rowSpan = keys.length;
                td.className = "rowLabel";
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
        for (var j = 0, m = keyData.length; j < m; j++) {
            var eleData = keyData[j].data;
            if(eleData instanceof Array){
             for (var k = 0, n = eleData.length; k < n; k++) {
               var td = document.createElement('td');
               td.innerHTML = eleData[k];
               td.colSpan = keyData[j].span;
               td.className = "colHeaders";
               tr.appendChild(td);
              }
             }else{
               var td = document.createElement('td');
               td.innerHTML = keyData[j].data;
               td.colSpan = keyData[j].span;
               td.className = "colHeaders";
               tr.appendChild(td);
             }
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
     }
     var tr = document.createElement('tr');
     var noOfbottomLabs = formatted.count ?  formatted.count / bottomLabs.length : bottomLabs.length;
                for (var i = 1; i <= noOfbottomLabs; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < bottomLabs.length; j++) {
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        td.innerHTML = bottomLabs[j];
                        td.className = "bottomLabs";
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
                function setToValue(obj, value, path) {
                    var parent = obj;
                    for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i += 1) {
                        parent[path[i]] = parent[path[i]] || {}
                        parent = parent[path[i]];
                    }
                    parent[path[path.length-1]] = value;
                }   
                var rowsData = returnRowsData(data), tempRows = {}, tempArr = {};
                for (var i = 0, l = rowsData.length; i < l ; i++) {
                    var names = rowsData[i].name, _data  = rowsData[i].data;
                    setToValue(tempRows, _data, names);
                }
                var similiar = {};
                for (var ele = 0, lent = rowsData.length; ele < lent; ele++) {
                    var curD = rowsData[ele], tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    for (var i = 0; i < curD.name.length; i++) {
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        td.innerHTML = curD.name[i] || "-";
                        td.setAttribute('val', curD.name[i]);
                        td.className = "rowHeader";
                        similiar[curD.name[i]] = 0;
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                    var merg = [];
                    merg = [].concat.apply( merg, curD.data);
                    for (var i = 0; i < merg.length; i++) {
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        td.innerHTML = merg[i] || "-";
                        td.className = "tdData";
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                    table.appendChild(tr);
                    console.log(merg);
                }
                document.body.appendChild(table);
                for (var text in similiar) {
                    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[val="' + text + '"]');
                    elements[0].rowSpan = elements.length;
                    for (var j = 1; j < elements.length; j++) {
                        var v = elements[j];
                        v.parentNode.removeChild(v);
                    }
                }
        }
```

And currently it is working like this http://jsfiddle.net/RwdWq/3/

How can I resolve this issue and page is going dead some times if data is big. Help me improve the performance and I want to check the possibility of making it without table.

Comment: How many rows does the output table have when you get perf problems? And, does behavious change dramatically by browser type?

Comment: @rlb I tested this only in Chrome...

Comment: "*this issue*" - **What** issue? Please describe it.

Comment: Your JSON format is odd, you have 3 different concepts for hierarchies: nested arrays (column headers, which looks useful), automatically repeated names ("columns under subColumns", without level information), and no explicit hierarchy (row groups). I strongly would suggest to simplify that.

Comment: would it help if I gave you a solution with template engine / 3rd party library (e.g: knockout js), or you want it with pure js ?

Comment: @AnasNakawa Yes that is fine with templating engine but not with third party libraries please.. My entire app ois built using pure JS

Comment: @Bergi Yes JSON format is too old. Because the same format will be the input for different plugins. So I could not change that. Thats is why somewhere I have tried to customise the JSON using JS.

Comment: I can do this in Knockout.js and ember. I dunno how to do it in pure js.

Comment: Can "Columns under subColumns" also be nested?

Comment: @AvnerSolomon Yes, they will be nested. What I have shown in data is two level of nested columns.. There can be multiple

Comment: @Exception 3rd party libraries are also written in Pure JS. Is it OK if you use one or two additional, helper *Pure JS* libraries, like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) ?

Comment: @Exception: Sorry, for critic, but your code is really difficult to read. You use many **duplicate definition of variables**. JavaScript have **function level** of variable declarations and **no block level** declaration like many other computer languages. So definition of variables `td`, `tr` inside of loop, definition of `i`, `j`, `k` and so on works in other way as it's written in the code. Another question: do you have more recent version of the code? One can see that the code from http://jsfiddle.net/RwdWq/3/ works incorrectly. Before improving performance one should fix bugs in the code.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for the suggestion. I have mentioned that I am also unable to fix that bug and I am waiting for suitable solution for this problem.

Comment: @RDX I am absolutely open to any library that does not interact with DOM much. Underscore? I am glad to use that library

Comment: @Exception I have written code for creating nested tables like this before, but before I put any effort into answering your question, I just want to know a couple things. 1st, are you almost happy with the existing answers or do you want a much better solution? 2nd, do you have some real test data for me to use and an example of the output that you want (so that I can compare performance of my code to your existing code)? Having that real data would be the only way I could make sure my solution actually works for you.

Comment: @Exception In the JSON data regarding columns, you have commented that it can be N level hierarchy. Can you show an example of JSON data with three level hierarchy?

Comment: Will the subcolumns be same for every column and similarly row sub group for every row group ?

Comment: @Exception, provided a new fiddle in my answer below - there was  a problem with groups.  This one shows a fairly complicated example.

Comment: @hoonto There's a link to [Meta] in the last comment (and in this one), which is where you can get insight into the community of Stack Overflow or question actions of the community, moderators, etc.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com.  It's also on the about page, in the title bar, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my jQuery-based solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>json2html</title>
      <style>
        #target     { display: none }
        td          { text-align: center; border: 1px solid gray; }
        .colHeaders { }
        .rowLabel   { }
        .bottomLabs { }
        .rowHeader  { }
        .tdData     { }
      </style>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var json2html = (function () {
          var json2html = function(json) {
              this.data = json;
              this.rgh  = json["row group headers"];
              this.ch   = json["Column Headers"];
              this.dft  = json["Data for Table"];
              this.cus  = json["Columns under subColumns"];
              this.sc   = this.cus.length;

              var depth = 0;
              for (var i in this.ch) {
                  depth = Math.max(depth, this.ch[i].length);
              }
              this.depth = depth;
          }

          function repeat(pattern, count) {
              var result = pattern;
              while (--count > 0) {
                  result += pattern;
              }
              return result;
          }

          function join(data, td) {
              try {
                  return td + data.join('</td>' + td) + '</td>';
              } catch (e) {
                  return td + data + '</td>';
              }
          }

          function renderSubHeader(data, index, sc) {
              var html = '';
              $.each(data, function() {
                  var cs = sc;
                  for (var i = index + 1; i < this.length; i++) {
                      cs *= this[i].length;
                  }
                  var value = (typeof this[index] != 'undefined') ? this[index] : '';
                  var cell = join(value, '<td class="colHeaders"' + ((cs > 1) ? ' colspan="'+cs+'">' : '>'));
                  if (index > 1) {
                      for (var i = index - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                          html += repeat(cell, this[i].length);
                      }
                  } else {
                      html += cell;
                  }
              });
              return(html);
          }

          function renderHeader(data) {
              var html = '<tr>';
              html += join(data.rgh, '<th rowspan="'+(data.depth + 1)+'" class="rowLabel">');
              html += renderSubHeader(data.ch, 0, data.sc);
              html += '</tr>';
              for (var index = 1; index < data.depth; index++) {
                  html += '<tr>';
                  html += renderSubHeader(data.ch, index, data.sc);
                  html += '</tr>';
              };
              return html;
          }

          function renderColHeader(data) {
              var html = '<tr>';
              $.each(data.dft[0].data, function(index) {
                  html += join(data.cus, '<td class="bottomLabs">');
              });
              return html+'</tr>';
          }

          function renderData(data) {
              var html = '';
              $.each(data.dft, function(nr) {
                  html += '<tr>';
                  html += join(this.name, '<td class="rowHeader">');
                  $.each(this.data, function() {
                      html += join(this, '<td class="tdData">');
                  });
                  html += '</tr>';
              });
              return html;
          }

          function mergeCells(cells, attr) {
              var rs = 1;
              var old = null;
              cells.each(function() {
                  if (old == null) {
                      old = $(this);
                      rs = 1;
                  } else {
                      if ($(this).text() == old.text()) {
                          rs++;
                          $(this).remove();
                      } else {
                          if (rs > 1) {
                              old.attr(attr, rs);
                              rs = 1;
                          }
                          old = $(this);
                      }
                  }
              });
              if (rs > 1) {
                  old.attr(attr, rs);
              }
          }

          json2html.prototype.renderTable = function(thead, tbody) {
              var startTime = new Date();
              thead.html(
                  renderHeader(this) + 
                  renderColHeader(this)
              );
              tbody.html(renderData(this));
              for (var i = this.rgh.length; i > 0; i--) {
                  mergeCells($('td:nth-child('+i+')', tbody), 'rowspan');
              };
              var endTime = new Date();
              console.log('renderTable('+this.dft.length+' rows): ' + (endTime - startTime) + 'ms');
          }

          return json2html;
      })();

      //==================================================================================================

      var data1 = {
          "Column Headers": [
              ["Column1", ["Column1's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2"] ], 
              ["Column2", ["Column2's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2"] ],
              ["Column3", ["Column3's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2"] ]
          ],
          "Columns under subColumns": [
              "I am column 1", 
              "I am column 2"
          ],
          "Data for Table": [
              { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group 1"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group 2"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group 2"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group 2"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 2","Sub Group 1"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 2","Sub Group 2"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]] }
          ],
          "row group headers": [
              "Group 1 Header", 
              "Sub group Header"
          ]
      };

      var data2 = { 
          "Column Headers" : [
              [ "Column1", ["Column1's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2", "Column1's SubColumn 3"], ["abc", "Hello1"] ], 
              [ "Column2", ["Column2's SubColumn 1", "Column2's SubColumn 2", "Column2's SubColumn 3"], ["def", "Hello2"] ],
              [ "Column3", ["Column3's SubColumn 1", "Column3's SubColumn 2", "Column3's SubColumn 3"], ["ghi", "Hello3"] ]  
          ],
          "Columns under subColumns": [
              "I am column 1", 
              "I am column 2"
          ],
          "Data for Table": [
              { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group 1", "abc"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group 1", "def"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 2","Sub Group 1", "ghi"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 2","Sub Group 2", "jkl"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,86],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,86],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,86],[1,2],[45,20]] }
          ], 
          "row group headers": [
              "Group 1 Header", 
              "Sub group Header",
              "abc"
          ]
      };

      var data3 = { 
          "Column Headers" : [
              [ "Column1", ["Column1's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2", "Column1's SubColumn 3"], ["abc", "Hello1"] ], 
              [ "Column2", ["Column2's SubColumn 1", "Column2's SubColumn 2", "Column2's SubColumn 3"] ],
              [ "Column3", ["Column3's SubColumn 1", "Column3's SubColumn 2", "Column3's SubColumn 3"], ["ghi"] ]  
          ],
          "Columns under subColumns": [
              "I am column 1", 
              "I am column 2"
          ],
          "Data for Table": [
              { "name": ["Group 1"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 1"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 2"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0, 1],[1,2],[45,20]] },
              { "name": ["Group 2"], "data": [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,86],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,86],[1,2],[45,20]] }
          ], 
          "row group headers": [
              "Group 1 Header", 
          ]
      };

      $(function () {
          var data = [data1, data2, data3];
          $('#dataset').change(function() {
              $('#target').hide();
              if (this.value != '') {
                  $('#target thead').empty();
                  $('#target tbody').empty();
                  var html = new json2html(data[this.value]);
                  html.renderTable($('#target thead'), $('#target tbody'));
                  $('#target').fadeIn('slow');
              }
          });
      });
      </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
      <label for="dataset">Choose a dataset</label>
      <select id="dataset">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="0">Data 1</option>
          <option value="1">Data 2</option>
          <option value="2">Data 3</option>
      </select>          
      <table id="target">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
```

JS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwjHh/1/).

Comment: If I choose rows are merged if two parents are having same name, if I do not want to merge like that,what changes are required.

Comment: You should simply remove (or comment) the call to the `mergeCells` function (and the `for` loop, after the `tbody.html(renderData(this));` statement).

Answer (score 15):

I know how to solve your problems. There are more then one solution of this. Your code is pretty long and all of my solution demands to rewrite almost everything you have written, so I will put here just the most importants part. First by first.

**1. Your json structure** is awful. I suggest you change it a little. This is mine:

**EDIT:** As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) said, my structure doesn't precisely defines order of cells in headers. Yours is better in this way.

```
var data = {

    "Column Headers" : {
        "Column1" : { 
            "Column1's SubColumn 1" : ["I am column 1", "I am column 2"], 
            "Column1's SubColumn 2" : ["I am column 1", "I am column 2"]
        },
        "Column2" : {
            "Column2's SubColumn 1": ["I am column 1", "I am column 2"], 
            "Column2's SubColumn 2" : ["I am column 1", "I am column 2"]
        },
        "Column3" : {
            "Column3's SubColumn 1": ["I am column 1", "I am column 2"], 
            "Column3's SubColumn 2": ["I am column 1", "I am column 2"]
        } 
    },

    "Row Headers" : {
        "Column1" : ["Column1's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2"],
        "Column2" : ["Column2's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2"],
        "Column3" : ["Column3's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2"] 
    },

    "Data for Table" : [
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 45, 20, 0, 1, 1, 2, 45, 20],
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 45, 20, 0, 1, 1, 2, 45, 20],
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 45, 20, 0, 1, 1, 2, 45, 20],
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 45, 20, 0, 1, 1, 2, 45, 20]
    ]
}
```

It is still not perfect, but at least it is human readable.

**2. Json parsing algorithm**

You started with some function render which could be imho namespace or constructor. Then you created a lot of small functions and after them looooong parts of algorithm.

Try to split your algorithm to more functions and set every function some main point like:

```
function parseJson() { ... } 

function parseHeader() { ... } 

function parseRows() { ... } 

function renderColumnsHeaders() { ... }

function renderRow() { ... }
```

Also you can make it as an object. Then you can easily add various functions like sorting, filtering or other stuff.

```
var MyDataTable = (function () { // this is namespace

    var MyDataTable = function(json) { // this is object constructor, it will probably just loads data
        this.data = json;
    }

    // these functions are visible only inside namespace
    function parseJson() { ... } 

    function parseHeader() { ... } 

    function parseRows() { ... } 

    function renderColumnsHeaders() { ... }

    function renderRow() { ... }

    MyDataTable.prototype.renderTable = function (where) { ... } // this will render whole table

    MyDataTable.prototype.filterTableBy = function () { ... } // filter that you can implement later


return MyDataTable; // returns constructor
})();


var data = { ... } // some data

var firstTable = new MyDataTable(data);
firstTable.renderTable(someDivOrAnyElementYouWant);
```

Code like that is almoast profi ;) Easy to maintain, easy to extend, easy to make plugin from it ;)

**3. Improve table rendering performance**

Why is table rendering so slow? Well, it is probably not because of table but because of large html that you are trying to include at **once**. It doesnt matter if you use javascript to make DOM elements or if you write DOM elements directly into html. It always takes a while to render it if there are a lot of elements.

Unfortunately, html rendering is synchronous. It means that everything is frozen till your function isnt done. It doesnt work same as for example animations or ajax (it is called 'Asynchronous JavaScript and XML' for a reson).

**First option that you have is use ajax** and load table step by step. Setup some limit for number of rows that you can load at once. Then:
* call ajax
* get json from ajax
* parse it
* get lines and render them
* repeat
Then your browser will not freeze. Rendering will be still synchronous, but there will be 'window' between two rendering calls, so various events and other stuff is done here. 
Simply a lot of short spikes will not freeze your browser same as one long spike.

**Another option is load data depending on user position**. User can't see all data at once. This is very similar to first option and it is called 'infinity scroll'. You could already see that on facebook, google pictures... there is plugin to jquery for this.

**Last option is use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` native javascript functions**. This technique also works with a lot of shorter spikes, except you dont use ajax. You load all data in javascript first. Then you render them step by step with these functions. Since these functions works asynchronous, it works well. But it need a little deeper understanding. I have example here of asynchronous calling. There are divs that changeing its colors like a rainbow, but it is not animation:
http://windkiller.g6.cz/async/async-html-render.html

**EDIT:**

**Posibility make it without table**

It is possible to use div elements or maybe some list instead of table. I don't recommend it.  Tables are here for large data and developers of browsers are doing their best to increase performance of tables. Maybe you heard or read some speculations that tables are slow. They were slow, but these times are gone. So stick to tables in this case.

Comment: Your JSON structure is even worse - it doesn't determine whether `Column 1` comes before `Column 2` or not. JSON objects are **unordered** key-value-pairs!

Comment: @Bergi They are sorted somehow in memory and basic forloop in javascript should work with json same as FIFO. So I really don't see any point why do you mention it in this case? Anyway if you still think that my answer doesn't fit well, you can suggest some edit. But with good example please.

Comment: But only somehow. It's not specified that it should be the same order as in the JSON string, and ES implementations can differ from that (basic) behaviour - some are already known to handle numeric properties distinct. There is no evidence that *they should*. Don't trust on that.

Comment: I trust your judgment so I mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 1**

I did try John Resig's micro-template engine, and found too much trouble with it, so I do feel that underscore is a good choice for this problem.

**UPDATE 2**

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298292/building-the-table-html-from-json-data-with-js-template/17353525#17353525

Here's a fiddle that should work for your data, updated in the other answer, but providing here for future readers of this question (and stackoverflow does not allow the answer to contain a fiddle without code, so I'm pasting here as well):

Using underscore and a tiny bit of jQuery but probably not enough to warrant it if you don't already use jQuery (easy to replace):

http://jsfiddle.net/Wzpde/8/

```
<!-- BEGIN: Underscore Template Definition. -->
<script type="text/template" class="template">    
    <!-- collect some info, better to do outside of temmplate,
         but to keep with the idea of doing it all in a template -->
    <% 
    //////
    // Collect the header data into the hdrs variable
    ////

    var colsUnderSubCols = data["Columns under subColumns"]
    var hdrs = [[]]; // Initialize the hdrs array as an array with one array element.

    // Walk through each column header
    _.each(data["Column Headers"], function(tophdr, tind){ 
        var n=1;

        // First take the first row of headers, since they are specified in a different format
        // than subsequent headers (they are specified as strings, not arrays).

        hdrs[0].push(tophdr.slice(0, 1));

        // Next, take the subsequent arrays that represent the rest of the sub-columns.
        // Note that these do not include the final columns, as those are also specified
        // differently due to the awkward JSON structure and are tacked on at the very end.

        var otherhdrs = tophdr.slice(1, tophdr.length);

        // walk through each of the array-based sub-columns

        for(var m=0; m<otherhdrs.length; m++){

            // As we are building the header columns by name, we need to iterate over the
            // over the number of headers that will be in the row representing this depth
            // of sub-column, so we aggregate the multiplicative value of each:

            n *= otherhdrs[m].length;

            // using the final number of columns for this depth, we can determine the 
            // column name by the remainder of our iteration index divided by the length
            // of unique column names at our current column header depth.  

            for(var i=0; i<n; i++){

                // Initialize this container of headers for this depth if it is not 
                // yet initialized:

                if(!hdrs[m+1]) hdrs[m+1] = [];

                // i represents the iteration index into the total number of column headers
                // at the current column header depth, and otherheaders[m] is the array of
                // unique column header names at this depth, so taking the modulo allows us
                // the correct column name:

                hdrs[m+1].push(otherhdrs[m][i%otherhdrs[m].length]);
            }
        }
    });

    // Finally, the last set of column is not specified like either the first column or the 
    // sub-columns in the JSON structure provided, so we tack those on last.
    // They can be tacked on by iterating over the last sub-header array with a nested 
    // iteration of these final column names:

    var finalhdrs = [];
    for(var i=0; i<hdrs[hdrs.length-1].length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<colsUnderSubCols.length; j++){
            finalhdrs.push(colsUnderSubCols[j]);
        }
    }

    // Push them as the last set of header names:

    hdrs.push(finalhdrs);

    //////
    // Collect group rowspan information into a groupspan variable
    ////

    var dft = data["Data for Table"];
    groupspan = [];

    // Each row is going to have some <td>'s applied, but it depends on whether or not
    // we previously saw the group name, so that can be done as a look-behind so-to-speak:

    for(var m=1; m<dft.length; m++){

        //Initialize the look-behind groupspan arrays if not previously initialized:
        // This is certainly an opportunity for some optimization.  But
        // as it is can provide a baseline for functionality testing:

        if(! groupspan[m-1]){ 
            groupspan[m-1] = [];
            _.each(dft[m-1].name,function(item,ind){ groupspan[m-1][ind] = 1; });
        }

        //Initialize the groupspan arrays if not previously initialized:
        // This is certainly an opportunity for some optimization.  But
        // as it is can provide a baseline for functionality testing:

        if(! groupspan[m]){
            groupspan[m] = [];
            _.each(dft[m].name,function(item,ind){ groupspan[m][ind] = 1; });
        }

        //Now that initialization of the look-behind goupspan info and the
        // groupspan info has taken place, we can walk through them and
        // build out some information that lets the rowspans be built later.

        //Provided a 3-deep group configuration and 4 rows of data, we wind up
        // with a structure like the following:
        //   [ [ sp1, sp2, sp3 ], [ sp4, sp5, sp6 ], [ sp7, sp8, sp9 ], [ sp10, sp11, sp12 ] ]
        // If an sp* above is == 0, then we skip putting in a <td> 
        // Otherwise, we prepend a <td> with the rowspan set to the sp* variable
        // So essentially, we are collecting whether or not a <td> should be prepended
        // to the row, and if so,  what its rowspan should be:

        for(var n=0; n<dft[m].name.length; n++){
            if(!!dft[m-1] && dft[m].name[n] === dft[m-1].name[n]){
                groupspan[m-1][n]++;
                groupspan[m][n] = 0;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    %>

<table>
    <% 
    //////
    // Now we can build out the table using the information we've gathered above:
    ////

    // For each header in the hdrs variable populated above:

    for(var i=0; i<hdrs.length; i++){
    %>
    <tr>
        <%

        // Be sure to put the group headers first, before the column headers:

        if(i===0){
            _.each( data["row group headers"], function( hdr ){ 
            %>
                <td rowspan="<%- hdrs.length %>" >
                     <%- hdr %>
                </td>
            <% 
            });
        }

        // Now put the column headers in:

        _.each( hdrs[i], function( hdr ){ %>
            <td colspan="<%- hdrs[hdrs.length-1].length/hdrs[i].length%>">
                <%- hdr %>
            </td>
        <% }); %>
    </tr>
    <%
    } 

    // Done with group and column headers, now for each data row
    // (but not the group titles, which get injected into the rows below
    //  with appropriate rowspan):

    for(var d=0; d<dft.length; d++){
        var dftdata = dft[d].data;
    %>
        <tr>
            <%

            // Using the groupspan information detailed above,
            // we can layer in the group titles with the appropriate
            // number of <td>'s and appropriate rowspan attributes:

            for(var i=0; i<groupspan[d].length;i++){
                if(groupspan[d][i] === 0){ 
                    continue;
                }else{
            %>
                <td rowspan="<%- groupspan[d][i] %>" >
                    <%- dft[d].name[i] %>
                </td>
            <%
                }
            }

            // All of the heavy lifting is done, now we can put the data into the table:

            _.each( dftdata, function( item ){  
                for(var di=0; di<data["Columns under subColumns"].length; di++){ 
                %>
                <td>
                    <%- item[di] %>
                </td>
                <%
                }
                }); %>
        </tr>
    <%
    }
    %>

</table>
</script>
```

Data with nested columns and groups:

```
var data = { "Column Headers" : [ // Hierarchy is not limited to two levels, it is n level
    [  "Column1" , ["Column1's SubColumn 1", "Column1's SubColumn 2", "Column1's SubColumn 3"], ["abc", "Hello", "A"], ["t1","t2"] ], 
    [  "Column2" , ["Column2's SubColumn 1", "Column2's SubColumn 2", "Column2's SubColumn 3"], ["abc", "Hello", "A"], ["t1","t2"] ],
    [  "Column3" , ["Column3's SubColumn 1", "Column3's SubColumn 2", "Column3's SubColumn 3"], ["abc", "Hello", "A"], ["t1","t2"] ]  
],
"Columns under subColumns" : ["I am column 1", "I am column 2"],
"Data for Table" :[
    { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group A", "SubSub1"], "data" : [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]]},
    { "name": ["Group 1","Sub Group B", "SubSub2"], "data" : [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]]},
    { "name": ["Group 2","Sub Group A", "SubSub3"], "data" : [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,1],[1,2],[45,20]]},
    { "name": ["Group 2","Sub Group B", "SubSub4"], "data" : [[0,1],[1,2],[45,20],[0,86],[1,2],[45,20]]}
], // here the hierarchy is not limited to two sub groups.. it could be any number..
"row group headers" : ["Group 1 Header", "Sub group Header 1", "Sub group Header 2"]
}

_.templateSettings.variable = "data";

// Grab the HTML out of our template tag and pre-compile it.
var template = _.template($( "script.template" ).html()); 
// Render the underscore template and inject it into the DOM
$("body").prepend(template(data));
```

**UPDATE 3**

New fiddle here fixes a groups problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ju7xz/6/

Answer (score 1):

I do know from personal benchmarks and many test cases available online that the DOM manipulation is affecting the performance of your code (you are doing one DOM creation plus about three other DOM operations at every single node of your data.)

Also, to a lesser degree the handling/concatenation of many strings, which are immutable in JavaScript, is a factor in this code. For example, creating an array of 1,000 numbers at a time and writing them out using `.join(' ')`  increases performance by about 40x for the job of writing the first million integers  (vs. writing them out one at a time).

See my comment above and let me know if you think it's worth it for me to try to work on this problem. (Problems like this are fun to me, but not quite fun enough to do it if you're already basically happy with the existing answers.)

Answer (score -2):

You can traverse your JSON with jQuery traversing functions for example, or use pure javascript, then you can use [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) .
In alternative to EJS you can use [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure) which is quite different, but looks more powerful.